# Is a knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that lies in a plane necessarily trivial?

Tags: knot-theory

A knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that lies in a plane is necessarily  trivial? Trivial means it is equivalent(of the same knot type) to a circle in a plane.

Answer (score 3):

As Rob Arthan points out, the Jordan Curve theorem isn't quite enough. For example, you can find a closed curve on a genus two surface that cuts it into two pieces but is not a trivial curve. Instead you need the Schönflies Theorem, which tells you the curve is the boundary of a region homeomorphic to the disk. Sometimes this is given as the definition of the unknot (a knot that bounds a disk). To see this, remove a small open disk from the disk. Then you have a homeomorphic copy of an annulus $S^1\times[0,1]$. Use this annulus to guide an isotopy between the original curve and the unknot.

Comment: In fact for this isotopy strengthening you need the Annulus Theorem, a very non-trivial theorem to derive from the Schoenflies.

Comment: @JohnSamples: By the annulus theorem, do you mean the fact that if you remove an open disk from a disk, it is homeomorphic to an annulus?

Comment: Yes, it is pretty difficult.  Voxman and Hall has the only elementary derivation that I have seen.

Comment: @JohnSamples: Ah I see. Have you seen these notes? https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/jordan/thomass.pdf
You get the classification of surfaces, which in particular, implies what you are calling the annulus theorem at a fairly elementary level.

Answer (score 2):

By planar knot I'd assume you mean a simple closed curve in the plane.  In that case, you can appeal to the Jordan Curve Theorem.

Comment: The Jordan Curve Theorem just says that the complement of the knot w.r.t. the plane has two connected components. I don't think it's trivial to get an equivalence with the trivial knot from that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe the question clearly, I'm reading a textbook about knot theory. I thought the definition of knot was unambiguous.

Comment: @RobArthan Indeed, what is needed is the Schönflies theorem.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip: quite so! I think you should write that up as the *correct* answer.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip: If I may ask a related question. I sense a vague connection between Schoenflies theorem and extensions of maps from subspaces to spaces, and knotedness. A spaces that allows for the existence of knots has obstructions to knots, while those that don't allow them don't . Is this correct, and, if so, how is this described? I mean, I do't quite see the relation between Schoenflies and knots. Thank you.

Comment: I get that Schoenflies shows there is just one simple closed curve up to homeomorphism, and Alexander's Horned Sphere is an example that Schoenflies does not hold in $\mathbb R^3$($\mathbb R^n$?). But knotedness, afaik, is about ambient isotopies, ot homeomorphism, as all embeddings are homeo to each other.

Comment: @MSIS The Schonflies theorem says that every embedding of a sphere $S^n\to \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is standard, i.e. there is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ to itself that carries the embedding to a chosen standard embedding. On the other hand, in the presence of knottedness, e.g. embeddings $S^n\to\mathbb R^{n+2}$ not all embeddings are standard, and in fact one could define knottedness to mean that a given embedding cannot be carried by a homeomorphism of the ambient space to a standard one.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious; i've been out of the game for a while :) , but doesn't Schoenflies hold only for embeddings of $S^1$ into $\mathbb R^2$ , or does this readily generalize for embeddings of codimension $1$ of $S^n$ into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$?

Comment: @MSIS I was referring to the generalized Schönflies Theorem! it is not a simple generalization of the classical theorem, but rather a very deep theorem of its own.  There are some category subtleties, but these subtleties don't apply in ambient dimension $3$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip : I guess Alexander's Horned Sphere shows codimension 1 is not sufficient in $\mathbb R^3 $?

Comment: @MSIS yes, good point. One needs to assume local flatness.