# Show that any simple closed polygon in $\mathbb{R^2}$ belongs to the trivial knot type.

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Show that any simple closed polygon in $\mathbb{R^2}$ belongs to the trivial knot type.

Could anyone give me a hint for the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jordan-Schoenflies theorem extends the Jordan Curve theorem: Every simple-closed curve in the plane is homeomorphic to the circle. The interior and exterior can be mapped homeomorphically to the respective complements.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem

This clearly does not extend to $\mathbb R^3$ which is why there are non-trivial knots in $\mathbb R^3 $

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664730/is-a-knot-in-mathbbr3-that-lies-in-a-plane-necessarily-trivial?rq=1  is this question answering my question also?

Comment: Also is this answering some of my question ?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664793/is-a-knot-in-mathbbr3-that-can-be-untied-necessarily-trivial?rq=1

Comment: @Smart: For the first link see the second answer , making reference to Schoenflies theorem.

Comment: @Smart, I don't see off-hand the connection to this answer for your bottom link, will reread.

Comment: Is there a place where I can find a proof for Jordan-Schoenflies theorem?

Comment: Try this: http://eretrandre.org/rb/files/Cairns1951_193.pdf

Comment: @Secretly: Sorry for the delay. Please see the Wiki page for proofs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem